# Do razors with more blades work better?

Tags: safety, advertising

A known disposable razor company is claiming on their web site that their current product is superior to their old one because it has 5 blades instead of three.

You can see the claim on the ["science"](http://www.gillette.com/en/us/products/gillette-science.aspx) page here, watching the "Why Fusion is better than MACH3" videoclip.

Do five blades provide *any proven advantage* in comparison to three blades? For example, less cutting, or a deeper shave? The company only claims it's better, however I don't trust them, as they show only pseudo-scientific crap instead of real facts on their site.

Does any science back their claims?

See also [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/node/5624861):

[image]

Comment: While the question is great (+1), I must say that "known disposable razor company" wording is extremely amusing, seeing how you use their brand name 1 line below making the identification 100% unambiguous :)

Comment: @DVK I didn't have any choice :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Studies that have ever been published or scrutinised outside razor companies seem to be rather difficult to come by.

The best I could find was [Measurement of beard hair removal efficacy using image analysis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-2494.1990.tb00538.x/abstract), a study conducted by researchers at Gillette (kudos to Solveig_A on Reddit for fetching the [full-text](http://www.reddit.com/r/Scholar/comments/nbwz8/measurement_of_beard_hair_removal_efficacy_using/) for me). Now, a warning: this study's primary focus was not actually about comparing two razors, but on techniques for finding statistically significant results even for marginal effects were to conduct such a study. That can make reading it a bit obtuse (I shall not get into why they might be motivated to conduct such a study...).

The first two experiments compare different types of shaving foam using a  twin blade and a single-blade razor, respectively. They do not include results in such a way as to make direct comparison possible. However, the third experiment compared a single-blade and a twin-blade razor (Gillette's Trac I and Trac II razors, respectively) with the same type of shaving foam. According to their data, the twin-bladed razor was 1.6% more effective than the single-bladed razor, but that they could not reject the null hypothesis (that they were equally effective) at the α=0.05 significance level.

In short, this does not represent compelling evidence that a razor with two blades is more effective than a razor with one blade, which does not bode well for the claim that five blades are more effective than three.

Cecil Adams, writing for [The Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/174/are-twin-blade-razors-better-than-single-blade-ones), cites studies by Consumers' Research magazine which consistently failed to find a benefit for twin blades, whilst noting that the single-bladed razors tended to last for more shaves than twin-bladed razors.